# How to implement User and Admin controller in Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to implement an admin controller in spring boot. In that, I am not aware of multiple login pages from which, an admin and user, both can log in to the web application. And can redirect to dashboard. All these pages should be accessible to Admin only. User should not be able to redirect to the pages which is not permittable to him. I don't know, what should I do to implement these things in my project. Please, anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Role based authentication in your application,

For more : https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/jwt-role-based-authorization